# If $A \in M_n$ be doubly stochastic then $A$ cannot have exactly $n + 1$ positive entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in  M_n$ be doubly stochastic.

Can we Show that:

$A$ cannot have exactly $n + 1$ positive
entries?

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of construction. The least number of positive elements we can have in a doubly stochastic matrix is $n$ (consider any permutation matrix). Actually, we cannot have $n+1$ positive elements.

Consider the previous matrix with exactly $n$ positive elements. For convenience, we can consider the identity matrix $A$. Consider the worst case, where we turn the element $a_{ii} = 1$ into $a_{ii} = x$, where $x \in (0,1)$.

Since we want our matrix to be doubly stochastic, by doing so, we have to add **at least** $2$ positive elements lying in the $i - $ row and $ i - $ column (regardless any other changes we have to make).

That means we have at least $n+2$ positive elements.